# Getting a list of signal strength in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, gsm, 3g, signal-strength

I am trying to get a list of signal strength (both cellular and wifi) in an android device.
Do i achieve this using the Signal Strength class ?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WiFi, you'll want to use the [WifiManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) and call the [getScanResults()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29) function.

For cellular, you'll want to create a [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) and handle the [onSignalStengthChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onSignalStrengthChanged%28int%29) event.

Comment: Thanks ! Could you please share a little bit more on how to implement this ?